# Toggle 2 divs with one button

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have one button. I'm trying to toggle 2 divs with one click.
Logic is next:

- On first click hide BOX 1 and display BOX 2
- Second click hide BOX 2 display BOX 1

This is what I tried, but only works on first click, if you uncomment code you will see, not checking visibility of BOX 2

https://jsfiddle.net/94hgwm1o

**HTML**

```
<a class="toggle-btn">TOGGLE BUTTON</a>

<div class="business-accordion">
  <h4>Business Accorodion</h4>
</div>

<div class="customer-accordion">
  <h4>Customer Accorodion</h4>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(){
    checkBusinessVisibility();
    // checkCustomerVisibility();


    function checkBusinessVisibility() {
        if(jQuery(".business-accordion").is(":visible")){
            jQuery(".business-accordion").hide();
            jQuery(".customer-accordion").show();
         }  
    }
    
    // function checkCustomerVisibility() {
    //     if(jQuery(".customer-accordion").is(":visible")){
    //         jQuery(".customer-accordion").hide();
    //         jQuery(".business-accordion").show();
    //     }
    // }
});
```

Comment: It would not recommend that you have a function within a click function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
jQuery('.toggle-btn').on('click', function() {
  checkBusinessVisibility();
});

function checkBusinessVisibility() {
  var check = jQuery(".business-accordion").is(":visible");
  jQuery(".business-accordion").toggle(!check);
  jQuery(".customer-accordion").toggle(check);
}
```

Like i said in the comment, it's not recommended that you initialize/create a function within a click event or other events like example (change, input) so on
.

**Demo**

```js
jQuery('.toggle-btn').on('click', function() {
  checkBusinessVisibility();
});

function checkBusinessVisibility() {
  var check = jQuery(".business-accordion").is(":visible");
  jQuery(".business-accordion").toggle(!check);
  jQuery(".customer-accordion").toggle(check);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggle-btn">TOGGLE BUTTON</a>

<div class="business-accordion">
  <h4>Business Accorodion</h4>
</div>

<div class="customer-accordion">
  <h4>Customer Accorodion</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but, works fine in JSFiddle, but when I put in Elementor  not working

Comment: @developer_wp Can't tell you why it's not working in elementor, but try check your console for errors

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery('.toggle-btn').on('click', function(){
    checkBusinessVisibility();
}); 
function checkBusinessVisibility() {
        if(jQuery(".business-accordion").is(":visible")){
            jQuery(".business-accordion").hide();
            jQuery(".customer-accordion").show();
         }else{
             jQuery(".business-accordion").show();
            jQuery(".customer-accordion").hide();
         }  
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="toggle-btn">TOGGLE BUTTON</a>

<div class="business-accordion">
  <h4>Business Accorodion</h4>
</div>

<div class="customer-accordion" style="display:none">
  <h4>Customer Accorodion</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but, works fine in JSFiddle, but when I put in Elementor not working

Comment: did you check your browser console getting any error?

Comment: No errors, I tried also different solution with toggleClass active and still same issue in Elementor